# Can't send with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I created a test host on 0fees.net. I also create a small php script that will receive the file i wish to send.

I tried a lot of things but server responds with HTTP 403 Forbidden; The actual message in verbose output is

```
* About to connect() to ********* port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 209.190.85.12... * connected
* Connected to ******* (209.190.85.12) port 80 (#0)
> POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: *************
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 791
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------4cad4df8
02c5

* The requested URL returned error: 403
* Closing connection #0
* HTTP response code said error
```

The code i use is

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.30 Safari/534.30");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Most of the curlopts stuff i added simply because i get the aforementioned http 403 error. How can i resolve this?

P.S
This code works flawlessly on my localhost setup!

Comment: Did you try accessing your script with a browser and with telnet (or netcat)? Did you look at the server logs what it says is reason for rejecting the request?

Comment: The script works with the browser...as for telnet/netcat; i am sorry i cannot operate them

Comment: Did you try looking at the log? That is the most important part.

Comment: Look at how the request looks like when sent by the browser then read the cURL manual to see how you can send the same request.

Answer (score 1):

403 forbidden usually means that you're sending a request either using the wrong method or to the wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

@dikidera I think CURL support is not available in 0fees.net

Check with this code

```
if (function_exists('curl_init')) 
{echo "yes";}
else { echo "No"; }
```